# Can Excel add new rows with cell references?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet with 15 columns and 93 rows; the rows are separated into groups with highlighted rows. I'm creating tabs for each row group, and only referencing certain columns (B, H, I, K, and E) for ease of reference. The main tab will be a master record, so when it's updated, the information in the tabs will be updated as well.
My main issue is how to update the tabs if a new row is added to the master sheet.
For example, the first highlighted row divider is on row 2, and the content I'm referencing for the first tab is in B3:B13, H3:13, and so on for the other columns.
In the first reference tab, the formula currently looks like this:

`='Main Sheet'!B3`

`='Main Sheet'!B4`

`='Main Sheet'!B5`

etc for the rest of the column.

If I insert a row in the main sheet at row 4, for example, the reference tab will continue to reference the cells surrounding the new row, without including the new row, which is expected behavior. I've tried both relative and absolute cell references, with the same result.
Is there a way to set up the formulae in the reference tab to automatically include new rows from the master tab, or would a VBA script be more appropriate?

Comment: Use: `=INDEX('Main Sheet'!B:B,ROW($Z3))` in your first cell and copy down.  Or just use a table on the main sheet and use structured references.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you!
As a followup, if you don't mind; what does the reference to Z3 mean? That cell is blank on the Main Sheet, but it's pulling the info from column B properly.

Comment: It is just a counter, all we care about is the the row number.  I use Column Z to limit the recalcs as edits in the cell to which it refers would cause a recalc.